# How to get caller's ( or caller's caller, or deeper in call stack ) instance ID - my.package.MyClass@3e7bfc04

Tags: java, call, stack-trace, aspectj

There is two questions actually.

First one is - how can i get such id (my.package.MyClass@3e7bfc04) having 'this' (inside of aspect, using pjp.getTarget() to get 'this').

Second one is - how in current program execution point (some method of other class, or deeper) to get caller's instance id. I can get call stack using

```
StackTraceElement [] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

and then decide if there is caller i need. Then i would like to get caller's instance id, but don't know how to get it.

Comment: found one solution to get reference id: 
String hashCode = Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(pjp.getTarget()));

but... it isn't equal to ClassName@HashCode, as i see in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) and [StackTraceElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) .

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = new Throwable().getStackTrace();

    String calleeMethod = elements[0].getMethodName();
    String callerMethodName = elements[1].getMethodName();
    String callerClassName = elements[1].getClassName();

    System.out.println("CallerClassName=" + callerClassName + " , Caller method name: " + callerMethodName);
    System.out.println("Callee method name: " + calleeMethod);
```

Comment: it's true that i can get className like my.package.myClass. I already do it, as i posted in topic, but i need to know what ___instance___ of this class calls current method.